# Is it possible to draw 12V from both halves of a 24V battery pack?

Tags: power-supply, battery-operated

[image: image_sample]

Firstly, I am fully aware of buck converters.

This question is all about the possibility of my imagination.

I have a 24V battery pack, powering one 24V device.
Because I am able to tap into the middle of the battery, I can draw 12V from it.

Is it possible to "merge" these two 12V sources, and then use it to power another 12V device? The idea behind is I want to draw 12V from both sides to drain the battery equally, and without any power conversion losses.

Right now I am powering two different 12V devices, and letting the battery's active balancer do the balancing work.

Comment: Does *another 12 V device* refer to a 2nd 12 V device, or a single 12 V device in addition to *one 24 V device*?

Comment: My final goal is to use one single 12V device, in addition to the 24V one

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible to supply a single 12 V load from both sides without a converter of some kind.

The solutions I can see:

- use 2 strictly identical loads (in practice there will still be a small difference, but hopefully small enough that the balancer will manage)
- use 2 different loads (lots of work for the balancer, maybe even too much). And as far as I recall, most internal balancers are dissipative, do they transform into heat the excess energy of more charged cells. So basically, you end up consuming as much energy as if you had 2 of the bigger load instead of one of each (which might void all the interest in not using a converter).
- invert your loads regularly (i.e. switch which one is on which side). Note that you will probably need some capacitors to provide current during the switching (excepted if power off during the switching is OK for you). You will also need to switch faster than the balancing.

Globally, if your 12 V loads are negligible compared to the 24 V load (or at least the difference between both loads), and you have a good balancer, you should be fine. If not, then I would recommend a good converter (you can find some in the 90-95% efficiency range). The last option of switching is not uninteresting, but probably too complicated to be worth pursuing (excepted maybe for very simple loads like light bulbs or heating resistors, for which switching off during 10ms is not an issue)

For the switching, the easiest solution is using a relay (but as you said in the comments, it has many downsides).

It should be also feasible using MOSFETs and diodes. The basic idea is to use 2 MOSFETs, one to cut the +12 V, and one the -12 V (if we call 0 V the middle point), then use a diode bridge to rectify the voltage.

[image: schematic]

Note that both MOSFETs should NEVER be on (not even partially on for a short duration) or your load will see 24 V! So make sure to add some dead-time when controlling the MOSFETs.

Also note that the diodes D1 and D4 are useless (current can't flow the other way even if you remove them). I keep them on the schematics because it seems easier to understand the idea with those extra diodes, but once understood, you can see that they are not required.

Finally, it should be possible to replace D2 and D3 by MOSFETs if you want to reduce the voltage drop, but it adds complexity to the control circuitry. It's up to you if you want the extra complexity and cost to save a few hundreds mV.

I let it up to you to come up with the control circuitry for the MOSFETs (and choose if you want to use an N-MOS or a P-MOS for M2: P-MOS is easier, N-MOS can provide lower Rdson but you need to generate a voltage above your rails).

Comment: I really hope that someone very smart out there able to come up with an ingenious idea or a module to "merge" those two 12V. Your switching 2 loads idea is pretty great indeed. Actually I had to add the 2nd 12V device with the same thought of helping the balancer too. But my final goal is to run only one 12V device in this setup. Btw, my battery pack quite big and the balancer can easily out perform this kind of task without even getting warm.

Comment: The switching can also be performed with a single load, it just has to switch fast enough that the balancer don't has time to compensate

Comment: All I can think of is the mechanical way of using a relay and a big capacitor. The limitations here are the switching not really fast & relay's contact will wear over time. Do you know a way of wiring some sort of power transitors to do the switching digitally?

Comment: I added a proposition with MOSFETs and diodes. It should be possible to replace the diodes with more mosfets, but it will be more tricky for the control of the gates